# Bypassing non proxy hosts in JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, gatein

I am adding non proxy hosts in standalone.conf.bat of getting portal server by

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.111.1.00 -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|172.16.31.* "
```

and when i am starting the server getting following error.

```
c:\jboss-jpp-6.1.0\jboss-jpp-6.1\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "c:\jboss-jpp-6.1.0\jboss-jpp-6.1\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
'127.0.0.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Try to enclose JAVA_OPTS in quotes.

Comment: I hate to be off-topic but I am really curious: why specifically 1303 megabytes of memory and not say 1300?

Comment: But not the way OP had it before the edit. **On Windows** `SET JAVA_OPTS="a | b"` will include the quotes in the expansion of %JAVA_OPTS% and thus get passed to JVM correctly. `"SET JAVA_OPTS=a | b"` will expand to unquoted `a | b` which will not work as desired. Unix is different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't leave a comment because I don't have enough reputation. I have also bumped into this question when I set this as an environment variable in Windows. It turns out you need to use ^ to escape | character instead.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/useless.php#EscapeChar

So this worked for me

```
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost^|127.0.0.1^|*.foo.com
```